# despite type guard in template, VS code reports error when trying to access property of derived class

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider the following code:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    template:`
        <div *ngIf="isBar(test)">
            {{test.someProp}}
        </div>
    `
})
export class TypeGuardFail{
    test: Foo;

    isBar(val: Bar | any): val is Bar
    {
        return (<Bar>val).someProp !== undefined;
    }
}

export class Foo{

}

export class Bar extends Foo{
    someProp = "";
}
```

This works fine when I run it. However in VS Code I get a wavy red line which says: `Identifier 'someProp' is not defined. 'Foo' does not contain such a member.` Obviosly this error doesnt make sense in that place and I would like to know how I can get rid of it? Also when I use this type guard somewhere in TS code I dont get any errors, so its just in the template where its not working correctly.

Comment: any luck with this? I have the same problem. I'm going to use the `$any()` type cast function for now (see https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-any-type-cast-function), but I would like the template to be able to infer the type correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still not able to resolve this error. Since I dont have that many typeguards in my code I just live with it.